# Redirection between storeviews; or displaying wrong language

Tags: magento-1.9, redirect, store-view, language

We have a Dutch (.nl) webshop with also an international storeview (.com), we also have a .be storeview.

If an user requests webshop.com/product1 the user will be redirected to shop.nl with a "server:nginx status:302" redirect.

Settings are as following;

- Add Store Code to Urls: no
- Auto-redirect to Base URL: yes (302)
- Storeviews; default NL
- sort order of all storeviews = 0.
- Base (unsecure & secure) urls are all set to the proper domain

  - view: nl -> https://webshop.nl
  - view: en -> https://webshop.com
  - view: be -> https://webshop.be

If I turn Auto-redirect to Base URL to "NO" and request webshop.com/product1 , it shows product1 on webshop.com/product1, however with the Dutch (NL) storeview & therefore the Dutch language. **I would like to show the "EN" storeview (so the product in English language) on .com without adding a storeview parameter.**

We don't have this problem in the Dutch storeview. If requested webshop.nl/product1 it will serve webshop.nl/product1 without any redirects.

nginx geoip_country_code is configured as well, however this should work properly.

which is mapped like this;
`

```
map $geoip_country_code $runcode {
AL en;
AD en;
AT en;
BY en;
BE be;
BA en;
etc ......

NL nl;
}
```

`
If I go to domain.com/robots.txt it does **not** get redirected to .nl. Also when I remove this configuration the same problem occurs.
Thereby I'm browsing from Sweden (which is SE en)

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, the default Magento functionality doesn't allow you to do that.

As an option, you can consider one of our extensions - Magento Store & Currency Auto Switcher:

http://www.mageworx.com/store-and-currency-auto-switcher-magento-extension.html

It uses the same MaxMind technology, as the ngx_http_geoip_module extension, but can additionally handle the Redirects problem. Here are some features that will help you do what you need:

- setting Store View - Country relation
- Switching between different Store Views automatically (by the IP address) and manually (on the frontend)
- Switching to the necessary Store by the browser language
- Redirect from webshop.nl/product1.html на webshop.com/the-same-product-with-different-url.html,(the same thing is for categories as well)
- specifying which  User Agents should be redirected, and which should not
- and more.